# React-Native: Error setting and getting text from ClipBoard

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard'

const App = () => {
    const [copiedText, setCopiedText] = useState('')

    const copyToClipboard = () => {
        Clipboard.setString('hello world')
    }

    const fetchCopiedText = async () => {
        const text = await Clipboard.getString()
        setCopiedText(text)
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => copyToClipboard()}>
                    <Text>Click here to copy to Clipboard</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchCopiedText()}>
                    <Text>View copied text</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Text style={styles.copiedText}>{copiedText}</Text>
            </View>

        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//styles
})

export default App
```

When pressing "copy to clipboard" i get an error saying 
null is not and object('evaluating NativeClipboard_1.default.setString')
and on pressing "view copied text" i get an TypeError Unhandlded promise rejection.
This code was copied directly from here: https://github.com/react-native-community/clipboard

[image]

Comment: Hello, which RN version are you using?

Comment: It is version 0.61.4

Comment: I would normally point this to a linking error, but I'm getting the same thing after linking the library.

Comment: I figured it out. See the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use react clipboard

Running example:  https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/4c673f

code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Clipboard, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const App = () => {
  const [copiedText, setCopiedText] = useState('')

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    Clipboard.setString('hello world')
  }

  const fetchCopiedText = async () => {
    const text = await Clipboard.getString() 
    setCopiedText(text)
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => copyToClipboard()}>
          <Text>Click here to copy to Clipboard</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:50}} onPress={() => fetchCopiedText()}>
          <Text>Click to View copied text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={styles.copiedText}>{copiedText}</Text>
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  ) 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  copiedText: {
    marginTop: 10,
    color: 'red'
  }
})

export default App
```

Comment: The React Native Clipboard component has been deprecated. They suggest you use the community edition, which is what the OP is using.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/clipboard.html

Comment: Clipboard component from react-native/community is not supported by expo. But when you develop without expo it'll work just fine

Comment: @parvdesai OP said nothing about expo. Out of scope imo.

Comment: @CoryMcAboy The OP may not have specifically written Expo but the logo in the screenshot shows that Expo is the environment in which they are developing. Parv Desai's comment is helpful.

Comment: My bad @MartinJoiner. I did not notice that icon!

Answer (score 13):

According to the Expo documentation (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/clipboard/), there's a Clipboard available from their API.

Install with

```
expo install expo-clipboard
```

and use with

```
import * as Clipboard from 'expo-clipboard';
```

Answer (score 9):

I too had this issue, as other users have said, `Clipboard` from `react-native-community` is **not** compatible with Expo.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. It ended up being a linking issue. I ran react-native link like the instructions asked, but I forgot to install the pod. Make sure you install pods after linking.

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Comment: Yes, this was the real answer for me :) Will I need to manually add this to my android app files like @mifi suggests

Answer (score 1):

manual linking worked for me:

mobile/android/settings.gradle

```
include ':@react-native-community-clipboard'
project(':@react-native-community-clipboard').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/clipboard/android')
```

mobile/android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation project(':@react-native-community-clipboard')
  ...
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.clipboard.ClipboardPackage;

...

@Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          ....
          packages.add(new ClipboardPackage());
          
          return packages;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after much research could find a solution by using

`import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Clipboard, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'`

instead of separately using

`import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard'`

*In expo `@react-native-community/x` packages are not used.*

Comment: Thank you for editing @Mario Petrovic , I will take care of such formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from @react-native-community/clipboard instead of 'react-native'.

you can import it from @react-native-community/clipboard :

`import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard'`

after installing the @react-native-community/clipboard package and importing the Clipboard  from it you end up with the above-mentioned error

to fix it just re-run the `npm run android` again.

this solved my problem