# copy from clipboard into react native(native base) Input field

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

we use native base Input in our forms and users are unable to paste from clipboard into the Input, any ideas on how to solve this?

```
<Field
        disabled={disabled}
        placeholder={label}
        placeholderTextColor={placeholderColor || '#a5a5a5'}
        placeholderTextColor="#a5a5a5"
        value={value}
        secureTextEntry={secure}
        style={style}
        multiline={multiline}
        textAlignVertical={textAlignVertical}
        numberOfLines={numberOfLines}
        rowSpan={numberOfLines}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        onSubmitEditing={() => onSubmitEditing && onSubmitEditing()}
        onFocus={() => onFocus && onFocus()}
        clearButtonMode={clearButtonMode}
        contextMenuHidden={contextMenuHidden}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        selectTextOnFocus={selectTextOnFocus}
      />
```

Comment: Check this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945656/react-native-error-setting-and-getting-text-from-clipboard/60948928#60948928